# AWS Codebuild 'SINGLE_BUILD_CONTAINER_DEAD' Error on Building Phase

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild

Nowadays we face at the below error sometimes on build deployments.

> SINGLE_BUILD_CONTAINER_DEAD: Build container found dead before completing the build. Build container died because it was out of memory, or the Docker image is not supported.

The build specs definition:

There are 7-10 lambda modules which is deploying with at the below buildspec. This script had been worked properly till last month, but this error started to occur randomly.

Is there a memory problem or AWS change some policy or something?

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
    - echo Installing serverless
    - npm install -g serverless@${SERVERLESS_VERSION}
    - echo Installing dependencies
    - bash build_specs/install.sh
    - echo ***************************
    - echo Installed dependencies for all function.
    - echo ***************************
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - bash build_specs/deploy.sh 
    - echo *************************
    - echo Build Finished Successfully on `date`
    - echo *************************
```